# How can I replace the value of a textarea in Chrome as user?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome.

Is there a simple way to create something like a user script (with javascript?) that automatically replaces the content of a certain textarea (id: `svn`) with another one, preferable by using a regex replace function?

For example, if the textarea by default contains `Text "any text"-Set Text`, then I want to replace it with `Text Set any text Set`. (Basically replace `".*"-Set` with `Set .*`)

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`htmlTextAreaElement.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), [`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **bookmark** tool.

1 . Open a new tab, save it.

2 . Choose to edit the new bookmark.

3 . Paste js code in the url.

The code may look like this:

```
    javascript:
        var el = document.getElementById('svn'); 
            el.value = el.value.replace(/pattern/,'text'); /* edit your pattern here */
            el.disable = true; /* keep textarea editable */
```

When bookmark clicked,the code will be excuted. All spaces are better replaced with `%20`. Keep all codes in a single line, that is:

```
javascript:var%20el=document.getElementById('svn');el.value=el.value.replace(/pattern/,'text');el.disable=true;
```

Good luck.